# Is it possible to use azure cognitive service on a webapp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am a novice in Azure and I am trying to create a web app with a text-to-speech agent using azure resources. So far I have the web app and separatly the voice agent. Do you know if it is possible to bind both so that when I click a button on the web app, the voice agent says something (anything would work for now).
If it is possible, what steps would you follow to achieve that?

I'm using .NET core and C#.

Thanks in advance for the time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use the Speech Services REST API or SDK. Here are reference [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/overview?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#reference-docs).

As well as the API reference document: [Cognitive Services APIs Reference (microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-curl)